# Basic scanner - finding directory

Tags: java.util.scanner

For the purpose of reading in text documents, I realize that I need to find the java file in the bin instead of the src, using Eclipse. How would I short-code that in my programs? Instead of using "C://Users/Brian/workspace/Test/bin/file", what could I do to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

```
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){

}
```

This is for what programmers should be punished for.
Do not ever make things like this - if there would be an error, you'll never notice this.

```
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

If your file doesn't exists, you can't read/scan it..

Comment: I just re-made my question. Your answer helped though. Thanks

Comment: If your program is running in "/src" path, you can go to "/bin" by: "../bin". Double dot means parent folder

Comment: I don't understand. I just tried and it didn't work. What do you mean? I tried "File file = new File("..bin/file");"

Comment: Almost. new File("../bin/file");

Comment: Still didn't work. >.<

"java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\bin\file (The system cannot find the path specified)"

Comment: Are you sure that you're executing from "src" path in your project's folder, and file exists? You can check your current path by: System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())